# How to disable an accesskey in an <input>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a predefined PHP framework, which I am to extend. jQuery/jQueryUI are included.

The site has some links with an `accesskey` element defined. For example, pressing `L` logs you out immediately. And there is the trouble.

Sometimes, pressing `l` in an `<input type="text"/>` logs me out. Sometimes not. Needless to say, it should not do so. I can't always reproduce that error, but I have not yet found out when it triggers and when not.

So, without being able to remove that `accesskey` element in the framework, how can I prevent that behaviour?

Comment: You need to know, what code triggers the l-accesskey. Preventing without it is imposible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should probably have a confirmation dialog for logging out, especially with such an easy way to do so accidentally.  Second, I'm not sure exactly how this `accesskey` code works without you showing more information about it, but it would be something like this:

```
$(':input').focus(function(e) { 
    // disable accesskey functionality 
});
$(':input').blur(function(e) { 
    // reenable accesskey functionality 
});
```

Comment: Does this also work with `<input>`s tat were added to the document by an jQuery `.append` call?

Comment: You would have to use `$(':input').live('focus',function(e){});` (and `blur`) to provide functionality for those...

Answer (score -2):

Disable the JavaScript on the Browser. Simple.

Comment: I need js for the very same extension I am making.